# convert html5 svg element to pdf without canvas

Tags: pdf, d3.js, svg

I created a svg element with d3.js which contains some  elements now i want to export it on button click as pdf. Does someone know how to approach this?
When I draw it in a canvas I only get a blank page.

Comment: Your question isn't 100% clear, but if I'm understanding it right, I would right click and save the SVG to your desktop, then use Inkscape to convert it to a PDF.

Comment: Have you seen [this post](http://nesterko.com/blog/2012/01/30/measuring-homophily-in-network-data-and-how-to-export-from-d3-js-to-pdf/)?

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cloudformatter scripts to convert d3 svg to pdf. See http://www.cloudformatter.com/css2pdf. There are several different examples there showing svg to pdf from various charting and visualization libraries.

Get their Javascript or link to it, its jQuery so you need jQuery. You can format the <div> containing the D3 generated SVG with on line. Assuming the <div>'s id is "d3donut":

```
return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('d3donut', {srctype:'svg',render:'download',filename:'d3donut'});
```

There are several other functions to embed, convert to image format or other print formats.

The d3 specific samples are at http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.SVGCharts.d3Charts

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your sample? We may have modifed the d3 script to add namespaces.

Comment: I will bet my above comment is why you are not getting an image. I can see in the modified d3 script for the bar chart on the page above:
.attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg") and 
.attr("xmlns:xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink") to add the namespaces for SVG. If the SVG has no namespace, you would get the error icon